# nuxtjs spa dynamic routes generate 404 after prod deployment

Tags: dynamic, vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I am using nuxtjs

- v.1.4.0
- spa mode set in nuxt.config.js
- with dynamic routing

When running in dev mode all urls work corretly, after `npm run build` and deployment to a weblogic server I can only access the webroot directly. 
From there the navigation to the dynamic routes work by clicking around.
However, when I type in a URL (other than the webroot) that should translate to a dynamic route, I get a 404 (but this works in dev mode).

Comment: The answer given below is correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because Dynamic routes are ignored by the generate command. You need to configure dynamic route generation by hand. See [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#routes)

Comment: yeah, i checked that before, but i do not do generate, i performed npm run build. as shown in the SPA section of https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands/

Comment: That's doesn't change a fact. You needed generate routes if you don't use SSR

Comment: Are dynamic nested routes and SPA concepts mutually exclusive? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820584/can-we-combine-the-spa-concept-with-dynamic-nested-routes-in-nuxt-js)

Comment: @BillalBegueradj no, it isnt. You just need to route all your request to index.html in spa mode.

Comment: Yes, I just confirmed that both in theory and using code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `fallback: true` to nuxt config generate parameter ([docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/netlify-deployment)). This redirects missing pages to `404.html` which then loads the `index.html`

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  generate: {
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was to convert dynamic routes to static routes and move the `params` argument to `query` instead.

In my case `/product/_id.vue` changed to `/product.vue` and references to `params: {id: product_id}` changed to `query: {id: product_id}`.

All `n-link` paths needed to be updated from `:to="'/product/' + product_id"` to `:to="'/product?id=' + product_id"` and I had to add [beforeRouteUpdate](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to the product.vue page component to handle nuxt links that changed the query, but not the page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `hash` [mode](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#mode) of the router - then you have basically just one route and nuxt can handle it in any case. Of course it is not SEO friendly but since you are using SPA mode I believe it is not an issue.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693617/7113416 for the orginal answer

Answer (score 0):

Just in case myself or someone run into this issue again, I am using Nuxt version 3.6.2, and my "dynamic route" is using SSR, and I ran into this issue.  My "dynamic route" page has a hyphen, like task-search, after removing the hyphen (rename the folder to tasksearch), the problem is resolved.  My nuxt.config.ts contains:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  routeRules: {
    '/vLoginRedirect': {ssr: false},
    '/vlogout': {ssr: false},
    '/**': {ssr: true},
    '/tasks/**': { ssr: true },
    '/tasksearch/**': { ssr: true },
    '/pages/tasks/**': { ssr: true },
    '/pages/tasksearch/**': { ssr: true },
  },
```

I really want this page to be render using SSR so having a 404 for a "dynamic route" page make no sense and defeat the purpose of using SSR.  I think that having the hyphen in the path is somehow causing the issue.  I hope that this help me or someone.

Also, I am using docker, and docker-compose.  Restart docker-compose may help.