# Validate hook function in nuxt js give me 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, nuxt.js

When i store data from fetch i need to make validation for params id that if this id in feched data or not , see below my script :

```
 validate({params,store}) {
    return store.state.members.some(
      (item) => item.id === Number(params.id)
    )
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without any more code, but maybe `this.$store.state.members` is what you are looking for?

Comment: I make it but it work fine but when i make page refresh it redirect to 404 page

Comment: Do you have dynamic routes in a SPA application by any chance? (mode: 'spa' in nuxt.config.js)

Comment: I made _id.vue in my pages root and the mode in nuxt.config.js is mode: 'universal'

Comment: How does your nuxt.config.js look like?
If you are getting 404 on page refresh you might not have generated the pages. 
Maybe you find what you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673290/nuxt-application-returns-404-when-dynamic-routes-are-refreshed-tomcat-server)?